# AND multiple JOIN statements in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a table for users and roles. I'm using a has many through relationship. I am trying to create a query that will find users that have all of the roles in an array.

ex.

```
role_ids = [2, 4, 6]
User.filter(role_ids) would return all users that have roles with ids 2, 4, 6.
```

This is what I have so far.

```
def self.filter(role_ids)
   results = User.joins(:roles).where(roles: {id: role_ids} )
end
```

The problem with this statement is it returns all users who have at least one of the roles in role_ids.

How do I make this statement give me an intersection, not a union?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for only unique instances of users who meet the role filter criteria. If so, then this should work.

```
def self.filter(role_ids)
  results = User.joins(:roles).where(roles: {id: role_ids} ).uniq
end
```